# How do you do aggregate calculations on a laravel project?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I am working on a ERP laravel app for a small insurance agency. It stores client data, vehicle data, car insurance policies, policy certificates and payments for the policy certificates. I need the app to display customer balances ie, the balance between the certificates issued and the payments made. I have done all the input forms and the database migrations, models, controllers and requests. How do i make the calculations and which is the conventional way of doing aggregates ie which file will the code be written in

I am completely stuck, i am pasting a link to my github project for yall to compile and assist where possible. Im making the repository public for a short period.

link to repo: https://github.com/danielmumo/insurance-agency

Comment: I a not following, what code is having issues? you need to share the code in here, not the repo (I would recommend you to remove public access). Share the code that you are stuck with and show an example please

Comment: okay, removing public access, thank you

Comment: hey @matiaslauriti, im stuck generally, i have multiple files for the clients and certificates modules. How do I share all of them here on StackOverflow?

Comment: Try sharing one and explaining what you would like to happen and what you have tried that is not working, mayben then, you can approach the other files with the same idea, else maybe, you can post another question for another one that is totally different. For now, post one (copy text, not images of the code) and explain what would you like to happen, what you have tried that is not working

Comment: Did you take your time to read the laravel documentation? https://laravel.com/docs/10.x

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I have taken time to read laravel documentation and I find that using relationships easens most of these tasks.  It is still a working progress but I believe I am on the right track.

Answer (score -1):

First of all use this code to get the required data from SQL(Hope you are using SQL), As I can't see your project on given link. Also I can't understand your question Clearly. This code will return you the aggregate of total money paid and no of certificates issued to a client.

```
    public function show($clientId)
{
    $totalPayments = DB::table('payments')
        ->join('policies', 'payments.policy_id', '=', 'policies.id')
        ->where('policies.client_id', $clientId)
        ->sum('amount');

    $totalCertificates = DB::table('policies')
        ->where('client_id', $clientId)
        ->count();

    return view('client', compact('totalPayments', 'totalCertificates'));
}
```

After that you can create a file like this'balance.blade.php', or can use pre-existing blade file to view your file in that.
As you want and where you want like this:

```
    @extends('layouts.app')

@section('content')
    <div class="container">
        <h1>Client Dashboard</h1>
        <p>Total payment amount: ${{ $totalPayments }}</p>
        <p>Number of policy certificates: {{ $totalCertificates }}</p>
    </div>
@endsection
```

Routes for this is:

```
Route::get('/clients/{clientId}', 'ClientController@show')->name('clients.show');
```